# How do you set background color and file name text in Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

I was originally trying to set the view options for all my folders and default folders so I wouldn't have to change them individually, but now I'm just trying to revert the changes that I made.

I followed a tutorial from [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/set-finder-views-for-folders-and-subfolders-2260912), but the background within the "Set Folder Views" block has the choices: white, color, and picture. I thought white was the same as default from the show view options from finder, but it's just white. I have dark mode turned on, so this is a problem.

I tried to correct this by using the color option and selecting black in the color picker. But when I ran this, the background turned yellow.

Oh, and I selected "Apply changes to sub-folders" without thinking. For the white option, I let it run for 30 minutes before I stopped it and realized what it was doing.
Then I thought that I knew what I was doing and I used the color option and let that run for 1 hour.

So now, a ton of my hidden folders have a light yellow background. The white option also changed all of the file name text to black.

I didn't think about the text, and I corrected the color (I still had black, but I guess something else was different). Once again, I thought I knew what I was doing, and I ran this without looking. This time, it changed the folders that I actually navigate to. Now, I have even more folders with black backgrounds and black text, so I can't see what's in them through Finder. Also, it's not even the correct color. It should have been grey.

I gave up on the visual blocks and tried to use an Applescript to fix this, following the tutorials from [here](https://talk.automators.fm/t/automator-set-folder-view-options-in-mojave-dark-mode/3385/2) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2716678). I wrote the following code, but I still get an error.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:user"
    setBackgroundColor(theFolder)
    return input
end run

on setBackgroundColor(aFolder)
    tell application "Finder"
        set subFolders to every folder of aFolder
        repeat with eachFolder in subFolders
            my setBackgroundColor(eachFolder)
        end repeat
        set the background color to {65535, 65535, 65535}
    end tell
end setBackgroundColor
```

Error:

Syntax Error

Can't get every folder of "Macintosh HD:Users:user".

I assume this is because there are too many folders. Then, I tried to just set the home directory, using the following code, but I got an error.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:user"
    # setBackgroundColor(theFolder)
    tell application "Finder"
        open theFolder
        # tell window 1
        set the background color of window 1 to {65535, 65535, 65535}
        # end tell
        close window 1
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Error:

Syntax Error

Finder got an error: Can’t set background color of Finder window id 3923 to {65535, 65535, 65535}.

I used this to get the default color (dark or light based on dark mode). I also tried {65535, 65533, 65534}, but that didn't work either

Is there a way to just make both the background color and file name color follow the default color scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the *view options* on a *window* in **Finder**, some information is stored in a hidden *metadata file* named `.DS_Store` in each *folder* the settings are being applied to. This *file* typically does not exist by default and is created/modified as needed.

A fast and easy way to reset the changes you've made is to delete all of the `.DS_Store` *files* from within hierarchal structure of your **Home** *folder*, and the following example *compound command* will do just that.

In **Terminal**, which should by default opens to your `$HOME` *directory*, use:

```
find . -type f -name '.DS_Store' -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -I % rm % ; killall Finder
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

Assuming the **PWD** in **Terminal** was `$HOME`, this finds all `.DS_Store` *files*, the hidden metadata files in **Finder** that hold these settings, within that hierarchal structure and permanently deletes them. **NOTE: Do not use this unless you understand what it is doing and have proper backups!**<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup>Obligatory warning. It is safe to delete these files as they contain no user data in the normal sense, i.e. documents, pictures, etc., and are recreated as needed.</sub>

---

As far as `set background color to {65535, 65535, 65535}` goes, it needs to be part of a `tell icon view options of window 1` *statement/block*, e.g.:

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell icon view options of window 1
        set background color to {65535, 65535, 65535}
    end tell
end tell
```